# is it possible to not give a primary key to an association table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I'm using phpmyadmin to create a database to control order made from a `companyA` to other companies. I created two kind of object that the company can order and that needs to be distinguished:

- Accessories (it can be batteries made by the enterprise using there `InventoryItems`, or bought from another enterprise)
- InventoryItems (it can be screws or nails bought from another enterprise)

[image: MCD example]

so here's what I got in my `deliver` table

[image: phpmydaminview]

```sql
CREATE TABLE `deliver` (
  `AccesoryId` int(36) NOT NULL,
  `ItemId` int(36) NOT NULL,
  `OrderId` int(36) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

everything looks great but here are my issues:

- I can't make an order that doesn't contain only accessories or only items.they can't be NULL because they are part of the primarykey
  so I tried to remove them from the primary key and only using the orderId but now:
- I can't link different Items or Accessories to one order.because it would duplicate the primary key

so I tried to remove the composite primary key to get rid of those issues and to create a relation that would link the primary keys of each table (this would help me be able to link the objects to the order and at the same time let me make them NULL)

now my question is, is it that bad that an association table don't have any primary key or is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Instead of images you should post `CREATE` statements of the tables.

Comment: It's *very* bad that *any* table doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: I disagree with the former post. An association table can function perfectly fine without a primary key. Though the whole *point* of an association table is that it creates a new row for a new association, so your second point would work either with or without one.

Comment: On a side note: Stay consistent with your naming. The inventory_item table has an itemid. So how does the inventory come into play? It sounds like there must exist some inventory table and the inventory_item table is the association table between item and inventory. As this is not the case, either name the table inventory_item and the ID inventory_item_id or name the table item and the ID item_id. Compund names make good names for associations by the way: order_item, order_accessory, item_accessory would be good names for association tables in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table doesn't have to have a primary key. So generally it's okay for the deliver table not to have one. What it needs, though, to guarantee consistency:

- Foreign key constraints of course.
- A check constraint that in every row exactly one of accessory_id and item_id is null and the other not null.
- A unique index on (order_id, accessory_id)
- A unique index on (order_id, item_id)

I'd probably use two deliver tables instead:

- order_item (order_id, item_id, quantity)
- order_accessory (order_id, accessory_id, quantity)

Then both would have a primary key (because item_id resp. accessory_id is not null) and its easier to query the data.